# How to have netcat server close after n seconds

Tags: shell-script, networking, netcat

I need to use `nc` in a weird way, where I want the server to first send a file, and then receive a file, and this repeats. I would like to have every instance of the server server close after some seconds. How can I do this in a script? I already have a client that can interact with the server.

Answer (score 7):

Some netcat implementations have a timeout option. For the [one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nc110/) on my system, it is `-w`. Thus

```
$ nc -l -p 2000 -w 5
```

will listen on port 2000 and exit in 5 seconds unless a connection is attempted on that port.

Comment: most `nc`'s suck these days, though, because they are not kept. `ncat` - by the nmap people - is the exception, i think. and, of course, there is `socat` if you have the determination to learn a new programming language.

Comment: This is incorrect. According to man nc(1): "The -w flag has no effect on the -l option, i.e. nc will listen forever for a connection, with or without the -w flag"

Answer (score 4):

Using bash timeout:

```
$ timeout 3s nc -l -p 2000
```

Comment: That will kill the `nc` after 3s even if it had accepted a connection.

Comment: ... which _may_ actually be what the OP was asking, but it's not what the other answers do.

Comment: actually I didn't try to accept connection... it was perfect for my use case (I need the port to accept connection just to make remote script happy).

Comment: You should clearly explain what it's doing. The question is unclear and people come here with different ideas -- in this case the other two answers do something completely different than yours: they will wait up to N seconds for a connection, and if a connection happens within the N seconds, they will accept it and will continue servicing it even after the N seconds have passed.

Comment: in my use case, I got remote ansible script which check 9092 port (kafka) and fails because kafka fails. since I don't care about this, I need a mechanism to make the port open. using nc in a loop did the job for me. ansinle tries to reach the port for 5 min, I made it to make ansible happy and continue execution. (after this I fix Kafka which is not relevant here)

Answer (score 3):

Because of the documentation :`The -w flag has no effect on the -l option, i.e. nc will listen forever for a connection, with or without the -w flag`

I tried `nc` `ncat` `socat`, no one can set timeout for server mode.

As  far as I know, only `busybox nc` can follow `-w` option in server mode.

So you have to download busybox which compiled with `CONFIG_NC_SERVER=y` option, or compile it by your self.

So that you can

```
$busybox nc -w 10 -l -p 9999
```

But my system's busybox didn't compile with `CONFIG_NC_SERVER=y` option, and I don't want compile it. So I use this solution:

```bsh
portnum=9999
(sleep 10 ;echo "T" | nc -w 1 127.0.0.1 $portnum) | nc -N -l -p $portnum
```

After 10 seconds, send "T" to localhost:9999

The full code is

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
portnum=9999
testmsg="Hello_World"
if [ "$( (sleep 10 ;echo "T" | nc -w 1 127.0.0.1 $portnum) | nc -N -l -p $portnum )" = $testmsg ]; then
  echo "Test pass"
else
  echo "Test not pass"
fi
```

If server received `Hello_World` in 10 seconds, it will print `Test pass`. Otherwise print `Test not pass`

You can try open another console, and type

```
echo "Hello_World" | nc -w 1 127.0.0.1 9999
```

to test it.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [peterph](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253394/479626)  the timeout (`-w`) while listening (`-l`) for connections works (only) with traditional `nc` implementations.

On Ubuntu [such an implementation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/nc.traditional.1.html) can be installed with `apt install netcat-traditional` and called with `nc.traditional`.